# What's the difference between these two indexed MySQL tables?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on modifying an old MySQL database which turned out to be designed improperly for the sort of data it was storing. I'm not very familiar with SQL at all, so I used SHOW CREATE TABLE to get the CREATE statement used for the old table ('interaction_old') and copied it almost exactly, with the only changes being a few of the column names and data types, to make a new table ('interaction_new'). Now some queries which were using indexes in the old table no longer use indexes in the new table, and I can't figure out why.

Here are the indexes from both tables:

```
mysql> SHOW KEYS FROM interaction_old;

+-----------------+------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table           | Non_unique | Key_name      | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-----------------+------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| interaction_old |          0 | PRIMARY       |            1 | interactionid | A         |   138996006 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| interaction_old |          1 | Complex_pdbid |            1 | Complex_pdbid | A         |        1338 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| interaction_old |          1 | Protein_id    |            1 | Protein_id    | A         |       13737 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| interaction_old |          1 | RNA_id        |            1 | RNA_id        | A         |        2806 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+-----------------+------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+

mysql> SHOW KEYS FROM interaction_new;

+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table           | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| interaction_new |          0 | PRIMARY    |            1 | interactionid | A         |   152311144 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| interaction_new |          1 | pdbid      |            1 | pdbid         | A         |        2924 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| interaction_new |          1 | pchainname |            1 | pchainname    | A         |         472 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| interaction_new |          1 | rchainname |            1 | rchainname    | A         |         487 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

And an example query that is behaving differently between the two:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT Complex_pdbid FROM interaction_old;

+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type  | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | interaction_old | range | NULL          | Complex_pdbid | 6       | NULL | 1339 | Using index for group-by |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT pdbid FROM interaction_new;

+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+-----------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows      | Extra           |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+-----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | interaction_new | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 152311144 | Using temporary |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+-----------------+
```

As you might expect, the query on interaction_old finishes in a fraction of a second, whereas I've let the query on interaction_new run for ~20 minutes before killing it. interaction_old.Complex_pdbid and interaction_new.pdbid are the same data type (and are storing almost exactly the same data). USE INDEX and/or FORCE INDEX doesn't seem to have any effect. What's causing the different behavior?

Edit: According to the documentation, the first table uses a [loose index scan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/loose-index-scan.html) to increase speed -- nothing from that page makes it clear to me why this doesn't work on the second table, though.

Comment: `ANALYZE TABLE`, `OPTIMIZE TABLE` ? PS: why do you store it in that way? Why don't you have a reference table instead?

Comment: If by 'reference table' you mean a table that contains the distinct pdbids, I do have one, but another query I'm having a problem with is `SELECT DISTINCT pdbid, pchainname, rchainname FROM interaction_new`, and it doesn't really make sense to have a reference table for the other two keys; I just used this query because it was simpler. Regarding `OPTIMIZE TABLE`: will this actually make MySQL decide to use an index that it wasn't using previously, or does it just improve the performance of indexes that are already being used? It will take a while to run, so I'd rather not if it's the latter.

Comment: "but another query I'm having a problem with is" --- create a composite index that includes all 3 columns for that. "I just used this query because it was simpler" --- it doesn't mean they should be optimized in a similar way

Comment: Is there a reason that I need to make a composite index when all three columns are already indexed separately? Also, I'd still like to understand the reason for the difference between the queries in the original question just to improve my (clearly poor) understanding of indexes, even though it's not the source of my practical problem.

Comment: "Is there a reason that I need to make a composite index when all three columns are already indexed separately?" --- yes there is - mysql can only use one index per table per query. Not sure about difference in performance - my proposal is to fix the roots of the issue, not the consequences.

Comment: I see, thanks -- I'll do that, then. I've also updated the main question with some more information I've found in case you (or anyone else) has any idea about that.

Comment: @user2217211 ANALYZE/OPTIMIZE TABLE will update  MySQL with actual facts about the table, and can radically change how queries are planned. If the actual facts matches rather closely with what MySQL already thinks it knows about the table, there's no change. You'll only find out by letting mysql analyze the table.